# Push notification open a new activity

Tags: java, android, push-notification, push, onesignal

I am using OneSignal push notification service.
When  user clicking on the push notification it is open automaticlly a new activity called "Main2Activity.java".
When the user clicking on the notification, the code is working and open a new acvtivity. But if I am sending another push notification, when the user is clicking on the notification the application  firstly open the "MainActivity.java". Only when the user click the previus button on the phone, it opening the "MainActicity2.java".
This is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();
    }

    class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"My Custom Key is:"+customKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open activity from notification then you put some data which is identify user came from notification

And when user press back button from mainactivity2 then check, user came from notification or any other place, if came from notification then close app.

Add below code in your menifest.xml

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Comment: Ok but the problem is when the user is clicking on the notification it is open the MainActivity

Comment: Then add this line in your manifest file,  android:launchMode="singleTop" theb your app will not open multiple activity instance

Comment: I didnt understand how to do that with the code. Can you help me please?

Comment: Your activity is open multiple time , is it true ??

Comment: Can you check now

Comment: Yes. it is working but the user can see the avtivity close.

Comment: Add some animation